# different content in div col md 6 equal to each other

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns using `col-md-6` but it looks like the left content float 'up'.

[image]

My attempt :

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<form method="post">
     <select name="satuanhari" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="7" <?php if($hari =="7") echo "selected"; ?>>7 Days</option>
        <option value="30" <?php if($hari =="30") echo "selected"; ?>>30 Days</option>
        <option value="90" <?php if($hari =="90") echo "selected"; ?>>90 Days</option>
    </select>
    </form> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <h3 align='center' style="float:left">In the last <?php echo $hari ?> days</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to make them look equally on a straight line. do you guys have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Remove `float:left;` in `h3` styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it come in 1 line. add a custom class to the 1st col-md-6 that has your form and give it float left. and for the  tag make the margin-top:0

```
**html**
<div class="col-md-6 form_div" style="
    float: left;
"></div>

**css**
.form_div {
float:left
}

h3 {
margin-top:0
}
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: can I ask? is it allowed to use `col-md-5` and `col-md-7` in bootstrap grid ? because the common pattern is like `4 4 4` or `8 4` @prithvi

Comment: yes you can use. depends on if you need it equal or one side wider than the other

Answer (score 1):

It is floating left because, you have added `style="float:left"` in the second column h3.

Remove it and it will come in a straight line.

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<form method="post">
     <select name="satuanhari" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="7" <?php if($hari =="7") echo "selected"; ?>>7 Days</option>
        <option value="30" <?php if($hari =="30") echo "selected"; ?>>30 Days</option>
        <option value="90" <?php if($hari =="90") echo "selected"; ?>>90 Days</option>
    </select>
    </form> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <h3 align='center'>In the last <?php echo $hari ?> days</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need `float:left` to make it look closer to the left content. the problem is, as you can see, the right content is like 'bottom side' and the left content is like 'upper side'